# CakePHP access uploaded file after validation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a field 'screenshot' that when I try to access in **beforeSave** callback the field it's empty.

The thing I do is access the $data on the **beforeMarshal** callback and store the array
into a model setting, then I can access that in the beforeSave and set 'screenshot' field to filename.ext if *move_uploaded_file* is true.

This is the current code:

**Model**

```
// Using CakePHP 3.8.5
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->allowEmptyFile('screenshot', 'update')
            ->uploadedFile('screenshot' , [
                'types' => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/pjpeg'],
                'maxSize' => 1000000 // 1MB
            ]);

        return $validator;
    }

public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
    {
        if (isset($data['screenshot']) && $data['screenshot']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $this->config([ 'file_array' => $data['screenshot'] ])
        }
    }

public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
{
    ...
    $file = $this->config([ 'file_array');
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception(__('Unable to move...'));
    }

}
```

**Form**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($project, ['type' =>  'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('screenshot', ['type' => 'file', 'class' => 'form-control-file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary col-md-3 offset-md-9']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

---

The code I expected to work

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->allowEmptyFile('screenshot', 'update')
            ->uploadedFile('screenshot' , [
                'types' => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/pjpeg'],
                'maxSize' => 1000000 // 1MB
            ]);

        return $validator;
    }

public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
{
    ...
    $file = $entity->screenshot; // this is empty
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception(__('Unable to move...'));
    }

}
```

Why is *$entity->screenshot* empty on BeforeSave?

Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, note that it's usually better to first and foremost show the code that _isn't_ working, and then additionally to that your workaround. Without seeing how exactly the former looks like, it's often pretty hard to give concrete advice!

Comment: That being said, I assume that `screenshot` is a field in the database and it's of some char type?

Comment: @ndm yes, it's VARCHAR since I will save only the file name (sha1 + some random string), I do this on _BeforeSave_. 
I was expecting an exception 'trying to save an array on string field' like Wordpress does. 

will edit my question with the code I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At marshalling time (when patching/creating entities), CakePHP will cast/convert the input according to the [**database types**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#data-types) mapped for the fields.

For your database field `screenshot`, which is `VARCHAR`, that would be `\Cake\Database\Type\StringType`, which [**returns an empty string for arrays**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.8.5/src/Database/Type/StringType.php#L96-L98). The reasoning being that the marshalling stage shouldn't cause "crashes", but ideally create entities with data compatible to the respective database types, which can finally be validated via [**application rules**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#applying-application-rules) if necessary, for which the errors can be as easily presented to the user as the ones for the validation rules.

The two most popular ways to handle this IMHO are:

- Using a different field name for the upload, one that isn't mapped to an existing database column, eg something like `screenshot_upload`
- Using a [**custom database type**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types) for the field, one that doesn't transform the array

Personally I prefer the former.

Comment: So this is why it's empty; will try that.
Thank you, this solves my doubts, also reference links. *noice*